# OpenMP and Threading

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, openmp, primes

I'm newly introduced into the stage of learning OpenMP, so please bear with me.

I have the working codes for getting the prime numbers under the specified number in the argv[1], one using the regular for loop and OpenMP. Here are my following questions I need for understanding:

(For regular loop)

1. In the file that uses the regular for loop how come each testing operation is logically independent to each other up to 100? Like testing 5 and testing 7 logically independent.
2. How come this becomes NOT independent after 100? Like for testing 105 how does testing whether 105 is divisible by 7 or 9 not independent from 5-division test?

(For OpenMP Loop)

3. How do OpenMP and pthreading work differently and how would pthread approach the task differently from the OpenMP?

The following are the codes. They are working fine. :

```
//prime.c    
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int candidate = atoi(argv[1]);
    int prime = 1;
    int h = 1;

    for (h; h < candidate; h++){
        if (h > 3){
            if (h % 2 == 0) continue;
            else {
                prime = 1;
                int i = 3;
                for (i; i*i <= h; i+=2){
                    if (h % i == 0){
                        prime = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                // if (prime != 0) printf("Number: %d is a prime\n", h);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The parallel.c: (With OpenMP)

```
//parallel.c (With OpenMP)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int candidate = atoi(argv[1]);
    int h;
    int prime = 1;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (h = 1; h < candidate; h++){

        if (h > 3){

            if (h % 2 == 0) continue;

            else {
                prime = 1;
                int i = 3;
                for (i; i*i <= h; i+=2){

                    if (h % i == 0){
                        prime = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                }        
                // if (prime != 0) printf("Number: %d is a prime\n", h);
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I not sure to clearly understand your two first questions, can you be more specific: what you got, what you expected...

Comment: If you're doing your homework, it'd be polite to admit it :-) (FWIW I think the question about pthreads is vacuous. OpenMP is normally built on top of pthreads, so it *is* a pthreads program, which is an existence proof that there need not be any difference in how you;d approach the task!)

Comment: It was homework and I forgot to cite it. Yes, and the question was resolved so this question is closed.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I'm pretty sure that I'm your professor. The coincidences between your code, your questions, and the timing would be too amazing otherwise. I'm happy that you're engaging the larger community in your quest to understand your coursework, but please be sure to cite such sources when you turn in your work.

1) Testing different numbers for primality is logically independent. Knowing whether 5 is prime tells you nothing about whether 7 is prime, and there are no computations between the two tasks that you can re-use. From the parallel programming point of view you can independently compute whether 5 and 7 are prime without needing to share any data between threads.

2) I think you may have misunderstood the question- testing individual numbers is still independent regardless of whether those numbers are greater or less than 100. Testing whether the number 7 is prime has nothing to do with testing whether the number 105 is prime. However, in the course of testing whether 105 is prime you need to find out if it is divisible by any of the numbers {2, 3, 5, 7 or 9}. *These individual divisions are not independent.* In the case of 105, you know that this number is not prime once you have computed `105 % 5 = 0`, and thus you don't need to test whether `105 % 7 = 0` or `105 % 9 = 0`. If you were to parallelize your inner for loop this is exactly what would happen- you would do a bunch of extra work you didn't need to do.

As an aside, you can't use the `break` statement inside a parallel-for loop in OpenMP. If you think about it you'll realize that such a thing doesn't make a lot of sense.

3) Again, the question being asked is slightly different. The question isn't how the *implementations* differ, the question is how the *programmer effort* differs. Think back to some of the Pthreads programs we have done- manually creating Pthreads and assigning work is significantly more complex than simply converting a serial-for loop into a parallel-for loop.

Lastly, I'll point out a few things since it looks like you're new to StackOverflow. The people here are usually happy to help with homework questions, but will respond better when you're clear about this. Be upfront with the fact that you're doing homework, and be sure to include your thoughts and reasoning that have gotten you to the point you're currently at. People here don't want to do your work for you, but they're eager to help you understand the interesting concepts behind your coursework.

Let me know if you have any other questions,
David

Comment: Thank you very much! I was about to cite it but I forgot to do it because I was occupied with it very much and I think I understood it now. I was working with the other members of the group too but I don't think the text explained to me very well.

Comment: occupied with things going altogether* (add)